# Woocommerce:How to add a file to the cart using api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to be able to add a file to the cart. That is, with any product, a file should be added to the cart.The file should be added automatically via API.I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Could you please check it - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8909

Comment: Are there any other options?

Comment: I didn't found anymore.

Comment: Or you can check this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341453/woocommerce-cart-is-null-inside-wordpress-rest-api